# Are the "Ubuntu Core Apps" also intended for the desktop?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, development

I have been reading a lot about the [Ubuntu Touch Core Apps](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/CoreApps/) initiative lately. Given Ubuntu's device factor convergence plans and the cross-platform Qt/QML foundation of the [Ubuntu SDK](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/), is it the project's intention to also bring the Core Apps to Ubuntu Desktop, thereby replacing their GNOME counterparts as default applications?

This would make sense in the overall strategy - and would be an approach I would certainly favor as long as the apps properly adapt to desktop screen sizes and input devices - but it seems that it hasn't been clearly communicated if this is a long-term (or even mid-term) goal or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is one goal, yes.  All Ubuntu SDK apps should be as usable on a desktop as they are on a phone or tablet.  Since the Core Apps are a major focus for us, and an early adopter of the SDK, you should expect to seem them incorporate the convergent designs that will be available.

As it is, you can already run them on the desktop, but their UI is tailored to touch-based input.  We will be fixing that soon, so they can switch between touch and keyboard/mouse inputs.

Comment: I would add, just to avoid any unwarranted sensationalism, that the Core Apps do not have a goal of becoming the defaults for the desktop, or of replacing any parts of Gnome or Gnome apps on the desktop.  

There may be discussions about this in the future, which will involve the community of Ubuntu developers, but those discussions are not happening yet.